# React: leave the contents of a component alone

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to have React ignore a subtree? i.e., don't compare or update it?

My use case is migrating to React. Re-writing all our Handlebars templates at once isn't feasible, but if we could use our existing templates for some subcomponents, we could adopt it slowly over time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, if you don't modify a subtree within React then the DOM won't be touched at all. It's easy to wrap non-React functionality like a Handlebars template in React. You can either use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```
render: function() 
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: template(values)}}>;
}
```

or you can simply return an empty div and populate (or attach event handlers, etc) it in componentDidMount:

```
render: function() 
    return <div />;
},
componentDidMount: function() {
    var node = React.findDOMNode(this);
    node.innerHTML = template(values);
}
```

In the latter case, React won't touch the DOM after the initial render because `render` always returns the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this module. Simple and very effective.
https://gist.github.com/alexeisavca/d4ff175fd16c93c8785d

Here's a coffeescript version of it.

```
module.exports = ReactIgnore = React.createClass
  shouldComponentUpdate: ->
    false
  render: ->
    React.Children.only @props.children
```

And wrap your component in it:

```
<ReactIgnore>
  YourComponent
</ReactIgnore>
```