# Is there any proper way to integrate d3.js graphics into Facebook React application?

Tags: javascript, facebook, d3.js, reactjs

Yes, I know there is react-art, but [it seems to be broken](https://github.com/facebook/react-art/issues/6).

The problem is that d3.js is all about mutating the browser DOM, and using it directly, say inside componentDidMount method, will not work properly, because all changes to browser DOM will not be reflected in React's virtual DOM. Any ideas?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/21290217/368697 from Ben Alpert on how to prevent React from editing subtrees of components.

Comment: No, this won't work in my case. The answer from @couchand below is much better alternative.

Comment: Are you wanting just charts?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

One strategy might be to build a black-box component that you never let React update.  The component life cycle method `shouldComponentUpdate()` is intended to allow a component to determine on its own whether or not a rerender is necessary.  If you *always* return `false` from this method, React will never dive into child elements (that is, unless you call `forceUpdate()`), so this will act as a sort of firewall against React's deep update system.

Use the first call to `render()` to produce the container for the chart, then draw the chart itself with D3 within the `componentDidMount()` method.  Then it just comes down to updating your chart in response to updates to the React component.  Though you might not *supposed* to do something like that in `shouldComponentUpdate()`, I see no real reason you can't go ahead and call the D3 update from there (see the code for the React component's [`_performUpdateIfNecessary()`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0.9-stable/src/core/ReactCompositeComponent.js#L1096)).

So your component would look something like this:

```
React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <svg></svg>;
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        d3.select(this.getDOMNode())
            .call(chart(this.props));
    },
    shouldComponentUpdate: function(props) {
        d3.select(this.getDOMNode())
            .call(chart(props));
        return false;
    }
});
```

Note that you need to call your chart both in the `componentDidMount()` method (for the first render) as well as in `shouldComponentUpdate()` (for subsequent updates).  Also note that you need a way to pass the component properties or state to the chart, and that they are context-specific: in the first render, they have already been set on `this.props` and `this.state`, but in later updates the new properties are not yet set on the component, so you need to use the function parameters instead.

See the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2Sjt3/4/).

Comment: At last implemented your solution in my app, it works very well! Many thanks again!

Comment: Is there a reason why no one looked into updating D3's SVG class to target React's virtual DOM? 
Reading the SVG code in D3 only the axis and brush (event handling) would need to be updated to target the virtual DOM directly. The rest of the code is creating arrays with SVG attributes/elements which React's virtual DOM already understands.
Most people are either redoing all the rendering in React or opting out of React and using D3's rendering instead.

Answer (score 6):

React can also render the SVG elements directly. Here is an example: [Ways of Integrating React.js and D3](http://ahmadchatha.com/writings/article1.html)

Comment: The referenced link actually describes using the solution above (returning false in shouldComponentUpdate)

Answer (score 2):

You can use D3 as a utility- that is, DON'T use D3 to change the DOM. Rather, use D3 for it's scales and axis stuff, but interpolate the outputs of those D3 functions into the html/svg.

Here's an example from my project.

```
 scale = d3.time.scale()
   .range([ 0, 100 ])
   .clamp(true)
```

...which is passed via props to a component...

```
React.DOM.rect({
          x: "#{props.scale(start)}%"
          width: "#{Math.abs( props.scale(end) - props.scale(start)) }%"
         })
```

where React binds the data to the elements, rather than D3's selections.

Comment: This is much better, otherwise you are not using virtual DOM

Answer (score 0):

I am using  useRef -hook to save reference to D3 visualization so that I can control when only the chart needs to be updated when there is other "stuff" in the page.

In D3 I am using reusable chart pattern outlined for example in here: https://www.toptal.com/d3-js/towards-reusable-d3-js-charts.

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';

import { select } from "d3";

const TestArea = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState(['red']);
    const refElement = useRef(null);
    const visFunction = useRef(null);

    const initVis = () => {
        visFunction.current = d3Chart().data(data)
        select(refElement.current).call(visFunction.current)         
    }

    const updateVis = () => {
        visFunction.current.data(data);      
    }

    useEffect(() => {

        if(data && data.length){

            if(visFunction.current === null)
                initVis()
            else
                updateVis()

        }
        
    }, [data])

    return (
        <>
            <div ref={refElement} className="d3container"></div>
            <button onClick={() => setData(['blue'])}>Update</button>
        </>
    );
};


const d3Chart = () => {

    let svg;
    let gElem;
    let circles;

    let data = []
    let width = 200;
    let height = 200;

    let updateData;

    function chart(selection){

        selection.each(function(){

            svg = select(this)
                .append('svg')

            gElem = svg
                .append('g')
                .attr('transform', ` translate(${width/2},${height/2})`)

            circles = gElem
                .selectAll("circle")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                    .style("stroke", "none")
                    .style("fill", d => d)
                    .attr("r", 10)
                    .attr("cx", 0)
                    .attr("cy", 0)

            updateData = function() {

                circles = gElem
                    .selectAll("circle")
                    .data(data)
                        .style("fill", d => d)

            }

        })
    }

    chart.data = function(val){

        if(!arguments.length) return data;

        data = val;

        if(typeof updateData === 'function')
            updateData();
   
        return chart

    }

    return chart

}


export default TestArea;
```