# Owl Carousel with React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I want to use [Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) with [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/), and I am new to React.

Please see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/6364/), I spent much time to do it.

The JSX code

```
var Carousel = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function(){
    $(React.findDOMNode(this)).owlCarousel({
      items: 4
    });
  },
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div id="inx-carousel-thumb" className="owl-carousel">
        {
          this.props.images.map(function(image, index){
            return (
              <div className="item" key={index}><img src={image} /></div>
            )
          }.bind(this))
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
});
var imagesList = [['http://www.myfacewhen.net/uploads/3908-troll-smile.jpg', 'http://www.captionite.com/templates/thumb-success.jpg', 'http://pauljadam.com/forma11y/img/rage-guy-teeth-smile.jpg'],['http://i2.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/004/073/smile.png']];
var Container = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      images: imagesList[0]
    };
  },
  changeImages: function(index) {
    this.setState({images: imagesList[index]});
  },
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Carousel images={this.state.images} />
        <input type="button" onClick={this.changeImages.bind(this, 0)} value="Images List 0" />
        <input type="button" onClick={this.changeImages.bind(this, 1)} value="Images List 1" />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  React.render(
    <Container />,
    document.getElementById('container')
  );
});
```

I included Jquery, Reactjs, Owl Carousel, too.

The problem is that when I tap button "Images List 1" to change the source array of Owl Carousel, the item count of carousel should become 1. However, it is still 3, and it only change first item. I think React only replace first item and ignore whole div, but I don't know how to fix it. Please give me some hints.

Comment: You shouldn't use the `index` as a `key` for a list. React cannot detect a change of the item (as the `key` won't have changed -- `index` at position `1` still is a `1`). If there aren't duplicates, you might be able to use the `image` value.

Comment: Thanks. I understand, but I try to modify it to `<div className="item" key={image}><img src={image} /></div>`, it seems not work.

Comment: Also -- if you open the JavaScript console, you can see that there's an error caused by the OwlCarousel manipulating the DOM, which doesn't work well with React (and in fact, causes issues as you see). Consider an option like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25514772/95190.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

1. You should deinitialize (destroy) OwnCarousel on `componentWillUpdate` and init it againt on `componentDidUpdate` after React rerendered the component with new images
2. You should return `false` in `shouldComponentUpdate` and manually update DOM  in `componentWillReceiveProps` using `nextProps.images` value and jQuery

Comment: can you give an example for this for owl carousel

Answer (score 0):

sorry my bad english!

You should verify length of element the carousel will use.

Example: in this case, my element is `.banner-img` - refer elements of `<img />`

```
componentDidUpdate: function () {
        if ($('.banner-img').length > 0) {
            $("#owl-home-slider").owlCarousel();
        }
}
```