# Guidelines for React with jQuery plugins integration

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, reactjs

Is there any guidelines how to integrate some already existed jQuery plugin with React?

There is a big library of already existed components and some of them is really hard to rewrite. Official documentation provides only silly high-level [description](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html).

Ideally a guideline should answer:

- where to start?
- how to avoid common pitfalls?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using JQuery plugins that transform the DOM in React Components?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436445/using-jquery-plugins-that-transform-the-dom-in-react-components)