# How to open popup in react-leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am working on developing a react-leaflet map that has multiple markers. My intention is to make popups open one by one with interval.

So, my markers are rendered by mapping an array and returning component

```
arr.map((item, i) => <CustomMarker isActive={isActive} data={item} key={i} />)
```

`isActive` is a value that says should popup be active.

`<CustomMarker />` looks like this:

```
const CustomMarker = ({isActive, data}) => {
  return (
    <Marker position={data.position}>
      <Popup>
        <a href={data.url}>Go to this website</a>
      </Popup>
    </Marker>
  )
}
```

I tried several things but none do work for me.

1. Implement through `eventHandlers`
2. Create custom icon using `L.divIcon()` and write HTML with custom popup. However, popup was unclickable as it was a part of markers icon.

How can use `isActive` value to open popup?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by getting a ref to the react-leaflet `Popup` component, and once that ref is ready, using it to call the `openOn` method of an L.popup.

First you need a ref to the map that can be passed to each CustomMarker:

```js
const Map = (props) => {
  const [map, setMap] = useState();

  return (
    <MapContainer
      whenCreated={setMap}
      {...otherProps}
    >
      <CustomMarker
        map={map}
        data={{
          position: [20.27, -157]
        }}
      />
      <CustomMarker
        map={map}
        data={{
          position: [20.27, -156]
        }}
        isActive
      />
    </MapContainer>
  );
};
```

As you can see, each CustomMarker takes the map reference as a prop.  Then within the CustomMarker, you need to get a ref to the `Popup` component. Note that a ref will not be available on mount.  You need to wait for the ref to be available.  But because useEffect's dont cause rerenders when a ref changes value, you can let the component know the ref is ready by setting a state variable in a ref callback:

```js
const CustomMarker = ({ isActive, data, map }) => {
  const [refReady, setRefReady] = useState(false);
  let popupRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (refReady && isActive) {
      popupRef.openOn(map);
    }
  }, [isActive, refReady, map]);

  return (
    <Marker position={data.position}>
      <Popup
        ref={(r) => {
          popupRef = r;
          setRefReady(true);
        }}
      >
        Yupperz
      </Popup>
    </Marker>
  );
};
```

The ref is only available once the component mounts.  In the `ref` prop, first we set the ref to our `useRef` value, and then we change the state variable `refReady` to be true.  The useEffect fires when this value changes.  The if statement assures that the ref indeed exists.  If the ref is ready, and `isActive` is true, the we call L.popup.openOn(map), and your popup is open on mount.

### [Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-swanson-0o3jc)

Or, if you don't want to bother with all that, ths functionality (and more!) is built in to a [react-leaflet-editable-popup](https://github.com/slutske22/react-leaflet-editable-popup).

Comment: The editable popup idea is pretty cool. Bummer it doesn't work with React 18. Maybe its dep tree can be updated?

Comment: @Midiman you can probably just install with `--legacy-peer-deps`, there's no code in there that wouldn't work with react 18,or just copy paste the source code.  There are probably [better solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75216099/12010984https://stackoverflow.com/a/75216099/12010984) to this now anyway