# Render React component as a custom marker icon in react-leaflet with working events/interaction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclicklistener, react-leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

```
    const IconGen = ({ incomingData }) => {
     
      const [dataMap, setDataMap] = useState({});
      const dataMapTemp = {}; 
      incomingData.BandData.forEach((each) => {
        dataMapTemp[each.AntennaX].list.push(each);
        dataMapTemp[each.AntennaX].angle= each.angle;
        dataMapTemp[each.AntennaX].sId = each.SID;
          });
      if (!dataMap[1]) {
 
        setDataMap(dataMapTemp);
       
      }

      return (
         <div class="container_Sector"  >
             <div class="circle" style={{backgroundColor : "#c31605"></div> 
                 <div 
              id = {dataMap && dataMap[1]?.sId } 
              
              style={{
                rotate: `${dataMap[1]?.angle}deg`,
              }}
              onClick={() => {
                alert("You clicked the sector!");
              }
              }
            >
              {dataMap[1]?.list.map((each) => generateSvg(each))}
            </div>
                 
            <div
              style={{
                rotate: `${dataMap[2]?.angle}deg`,
              }}
            >
              {dataMap[2]?.list.map((each) => generateSvg(each))}
            </div>
            <div 
              style={{
                rotate: `${dataMap[3]?.angle}deg`,
              }}
            >
              {dataMap[3]?.list.map((each) => generateSvg(each))}
            </div>
          </div>
        
      );
    };
    export default IconGen;
```

```
    //Parent Component

    <MapContainer>
       <Marker
               key={data.SiteID}
               position={[data.Latitude, data.Longitude]}
               icon = <IconGen
                incomingData={data}
     
              />
               
             >
     
             </Marker>
    </Mapcontainer>
```

I am able to render custom icon using `icon={L.divIcon({ className: "custom icon", html: ReactDOMServer.renderToString( <MyComponent/> ) })}`.

However the `onClick` within the custom icon component does not trigger. `onClick` is not working due to rendering the MyComponent using `ReactDOMServer.renderToString`.

I need the `onClick` event inside the custom component to function correctly.

Comment: Why are you using `ReactDOMServer.renderToString()`? What is the variable `L`? If you render to string the react runtime is not controlling that component and so any interactions defined within that component will not work, as you are seeing.

Comment: L is leaflet. I need customized marker in the Map. So i have designed separate component with svg images. My single marker designed with 3 images. Onclick of 1 image i have open a dialog/popup in Map. To render my customozed icon in html format , i have used  ReactDOMServer.renderToString().

Comment: And i tried  with react-leaflet-enhanced-marker to render Marker using static React Component.                                                                                                                                 <Map center={this.state.center} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
          <TileLayer
          />
          <Marker icon={<MyComponent/>} position={this.state.center} />
        </Map>

Comment: So the marker has different clickable elements inside? Its not practically possible this way. The problem is, by design, leaflet restricts the icon to static HTML. The `renderToString()` trick (which ` react-leaflet-enhanced-marker` also uses under the hood) will allow for a HTML string to be produced from a react component -- but crucially, it will *not* be a fully interactible  component. The react runtime is not managing that content or even aware of it beyond the initial call to `renderToString`. However, please share the code of this icon. It may be possible to workaround this.

Comment: Give me some time to put an answer together, I have a working solution

Comment: i have added the snippet

Answer (score 3):

**I have now published this solution as a library at [@adamscybot/react-leaflet-component-marker](https://github.com/adamscybot/react-leaflet-component-marker)**.

The reason that the `onClick` handler does not work is that `renderToString` means the component isn't truly mounted, in the sense that React is not aware of it as an ongoing concern. Running `renderToString` reduces the component to whatever the DOM looks like for that component on its first render, and nothing else will change that from the point `renderToString` is called.

The base problem here is that the `react-leaflet` library doesn't support this out of the box. However, we could get around this by:

1. Using `L.divIcon` to render a dummy div as the icon containing nothing. We will assign a unique ID for that div for each marker, which will come in handy later.
2. Using the `Marker` components `add` event to detect when the icon has actually been rendered to the DOM.
3. When this happens, render the real React component inside the dummy marker by using a React [portal](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal) that targets the div with the aforementioned unique ID.
4. Additionally detect when the marker is removed and remove the portal.

We can encapsulate this behaviour in an `EnhancedMarker` component, for ease of use.

Here is a working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/objective-hooks-r9jrw4?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A1%2C1-72%2C1) of the proof of concept. In this proof of concept, I am rendering two buttons as a marker, each with click events that work.

The below includes the generic code that can be applied to any situation:

```
import React, { useState, useId, useMemo } from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker } from "react-leaflet";

// `EnhancedMarker` has the same API as `Marker`, apart from the `icon` can be a React component.
const EnhancedMarker = ({
  eventHandlers,
  icon: providedIcon,
  ...otherProps
}) => {
  const [markerRendered, setMarkerRendered] = useState(false);
  const id = "marker-" + useId();

  const icon = useMemo(
    () =>
      L.divIcon({
        html: `<div id="${id}"></div>`,
      }),
    [id]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Marker
        {...otherProps}
        eventHandlers={{
          ...eventHandlers,
          add: (...args) => {
            setMarkerRendered(true);
            if (eventHandlers?.add) eventHandlers.add(...args);
          },
          remove: (...args) => {
            setMarkerRendered(false);
            if (eventHandlers?.remove) eventHandlers.remove(...args);
          },
        }}
        icon={icon}
      />
      {markerRendered &&
        createPortal(providedIcon, document.getElementById(id))}
    </>
  );
};

const MarkerIconExample = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => console.log("button 1 clicked")}>Button 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => console.log("button 2 clicked")}>Button 2</button>
    </>
  );
};

const CENTER = [51.505, -0.091];
const ZOOM = 13;
const App = () => {
  return (
    <MapContainer center={CENTER} zoom={ZOOM}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <EnhancedMarker position={CENTER} icon={<MarkerIconExample />} />
    </MapContainer>
  );
};
```

For your example, you should be able to:

1. Copy in the new `EnhancedMarker` component.
2. Change existing usages of `<Marker>` in your use case to `<EnhancedMarker>`.
3. Simply use `<IconGen />` in the `<EnhancedMarker>` `icon` prop.