# Rollup ESM generates broken imports

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rollupjs

I want to bundle a typescript react App as a component into a ES module or UMD.
But the generated ES bundle produces an invalid module js.

On bundle it gives me this hints. But I cant find any solution for this.

```
(!) Missing global variable names
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
http (guessing 'http')
...
```

inside the esm js bundle there are imports like these:

```
import http from 'http';
import https from 'https';
import url from 'url';
import require$$0 from 'stream';
...

function createCommonjsModule(fn) {
  var module = { exports: {} };
    return fn(module, module.exports), module.exports;
}
```

And after adding it to the browser:

```
<script type="module" src="./index.esm.js"></script>
```

I got the error about the missing relative imports:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "http". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

Iam surely have mistakes on my rollup configuration, but I cant find the spot and happy and thankful about any hints.
...

Of course I have nodemodule imports in my app like:

```
import {observer} from 'mobx-react';
```

But rollup should handle this. Dont he?

Here is my rollup.config:

```
import pkg from './package.json';
import nodeResolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import image from "@rollup/plugin-image";
import styles from "rollup-plugin-styles";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import replace from "@rollup/plugin-replace";
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import copy from "rollup-plugin-copy";
import del from "rollup-plugin-delete";

export default {
    input: pkg.source,
    output: [
        {
            file: pkg.module,
            format: 'es',
            sourcemap: false
        },
        {
            file: "dist/index.umd.js",
            format: 'umd',
            sourcemap: true
        },
    ],
    plugins: [
        del({targets: 'dist/*'}),
        nodeResolve({
            mainFields: ['jsnext:main', 'module', 'main'],
            dedupe: [ 'react', 'react-dom' ]
        }),
        replace({
            preventAssignment: false,
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
            __buildDate__: () => JSON.stringify(new Date())
        }),
        json(),
        typescript(),
        styles(),
        copy({
            targets: [
                {src: 'public/**/*', dest: 'dist'}
            ]
        }),
        babel({ //disabled cause WebComponent integration
            presets: ["@babel/preset-react"],
            exclude: 'node_modules/**',
            babelHelpers: 'bundled'
        }),
        commonjs(),
        image()
    ]
};
```

Comment: Sounds to me as if you're trying to use node's `http` module inside the browser?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with that.
But Iam realy try to render the main react-component into a div straight for test:
`<div id="comp-test"></div>`  aaand: `ReactDOM.render(...., getElement("comp-test")`
like this.
But I dont even come this far. The rollup bundle is producing the error direct on bind.

Comment: You are accessing the `http` module (e.g. `import http from 'http';`) which would only work in NodeJS (server-side) for a TypeScript **React** app, which would run client-side in the browser?

Comment: Jeah, I understand this issue. What wonders me is: this broken import is created by Rollup ES output. I dont have any of these imports in my code.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm getting the same problem when trying to use `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup()`, it says it can't resolve 'stream' which is a node package. It sounds very similar to your problem.  I think my reactdomserver isn't getting "browserified" or whatever because I have it as a global inline script that doesn't get processed because I run multiple instances of react on one page. Damn conflicting requirements. React won't let you have multiple instances so you have to include it once on the page and then load everything else excluding react so it's not built.

Comment: I've decided to workaround the issue by just not using this react function because it's becoming too much of a pain to debug these esoteric errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue (though with `stream` module, not `http`), and for me the solution was to set `browser: true` in `nodeResolve` within `rollup.config`:

```js
export default [
  {
    input: '...',
    plugins: [
      nodeResolve({
        'browser': true,
      }),
      commonjs(),
    ],
    output: {
       ...
    }
  }
];
```

From description of a flag:

**browser**

Type: `Boolean`
Default: `false`

If `true`, instructs the plugin to use the browser module resolutions in `package.json` and adds `'browser'` to `exportConditions` if it is not present so browser conditionals in `exports` are applied. If `false`, any browser properties in package files will be ignored. Alternatively, a value of `'browser'` can be added to both the `mainFields` and `exportConditions` options, however this option takes precedence over `mainFields`.

Answer (score 1):

I found that with tree-shaking off, it included these modules that are only available in node, but with treeshaking on it fixed the build and didn't include the packages http, https, or url.

It seems like one of the dependencies required these modules and setting browser:true in nodeResolve did not help me. Tree shaking did because they were not ultimately used in my code.

Addendum: The same problem happened to me a second time, this time with the crypto module and I had to also add browser:true to fix it.