# Using container's children in react render as children

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to use dom element(s) as children in JSX when rendering a component?  I think this explains what I'm attempting but is invalid.

```
<div id="container">
 <div>node 1</div>
 <div>node 2</div>
</div>

const container = document.querySelector('#container');
ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent>{container.children}</MyComponent>,
  container
);
```

Comment: Even if it did, why would you want this? Remember, React is your UI framework, and is in charge of the entire UI you present to your users. Even if you have static initial HTML, that should be static HTML that you generated from your initial UI state, not the other way around.

Comment: Tasked with converting a riot js component to a react one.  This is how the initial state is presented using riot's yield concept.

Comment: Fair enough - in that this case this is a duplicate of [React: leave the contents of a component alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285262/react-leave-the-contents-of-a-component-alone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), but it is not recommended.

From the docs:

> dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React’s replacement for using innerHTML in the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function App(){
  const [html, setHtml] = useState('Loading...');
  useEffect(()=>{
    setHtml(document.querySelector('#container').innerHTML);
  }, []);
  
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}}/>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

```css
#container {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.5/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.5/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>

<div id="container">
  <div>node 1</div>
  <div>node 2</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this will still update the content on rerenders (which may cause things like external referrences to become invalid). What you really want is to tell React to not touch these things at all after initial render, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21290217/740553

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Good catch, thanks. Using 16.8 here so I will use `useEffect`.